# Prevent UIButton Long Press Repeating Function

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

The following UILongPressGestureRecognizer code works, however it repeatedly runs the long() press function when the button is held.  I'd like to have it only run one time while the user is pressing.  Is this possible?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector (tap))  
    let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(long))  
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    shiftBtn.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    shiftBtn.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
}

@objc func tap() {
    print("Short Tap")
}

@objc func long() {
    print("Long press")
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the `long` When `gesture` activated. it's called one time whenever long `gesture` active.

```
  @objc  func hitlongprass(_ sender : Any){

        guard let longPress = sender as? UILongPressGestureRecognizer else
        { return }

        if longPress.state == .began { // When gesture activated
            long()
        }
        else if longPress.state == .changed { // gesture Calls multiple times by time changed 

        }
        else if longPress.state == .ended { // When gesture end

        }
    }

   func long() {
        print("Long press")
   }
```

Calling:

```
let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hitlongprass(_:)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check state of gesture in `long` function. Ex check state is begin long press